# Display indication for tags where a user is top answerer/asker on the user page

Tags: feature-request, tags, profile-page

On the user page, would it be possible to display some indication that the user is a top answerer/asker for a given tag. That could possibly be an icon or some graphical indication next to the list of tags for a user.

Something like that:

[image]

When I open user profiles, it's sometimes not easy to know that a person is in the top group for some tags which have less score overall.

Comment: The ranking is there anyway - just 2 clicks away.

Comment: What makes someone a "top answerer/asker"? Just presence on the "top users" page?

Comment: Yes, to make it consistent with "top users" page.

Comment: Yes, it's just 2 clicks away, so why complicate the UI with something that likely needs to be explained somewhere? If we were to do this, I'm willing to bet we'll see at least a dozen questions about it, and countless more searching for an explanation.

Comment: @Dukeling that's a fair point.